# Pick File From Ios Storage Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I used Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker To pick pdf Files , it works well in Android but in ios it pick file from iCloud only , I want to pick pdf Files from IOS storage,i searched for that but i haven't found the correct answer yet.

Comment: Where do you want to select files from on iOS?  iOS does not let you browse the file system like a desktop app can

Comment: yes i want to select file from file system ,,there is no way to do that ? @jason

Comment: I know you want to use the file system.  I need to know WHERE in the file system.  Are you looking in your own app's folders, or do you want to look in another app's folders, or some special system folder, or something else entirely?

Comment: I want to open the file system as a whole Not a specific folder for choosing PDF or Word files

Comment: it sounds like you do not understand the concept of sandboxing - please review the docs https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I will read about it

Comment: The file system in iOS is different from Android. You can't open the file system as a whole  in iOS.